# Add a three.js AudioAnalyser to an HLS Stream

Tags: three.js, http-live-streaming, audio-streaming, web-audio-api, hls.js

Is it possible to add a three.js AudioAnalyser (or WebAPI AnalyserNode) to an Hls audio stream? This is what I have so far and average frequency always returns 0.

```
        let audioContext = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

        let streamAudio = document.querySelector('#player');

        if (Hls.isSupported()) {

            hls.loadSource('https://stream.revma.ihrhls.com/zc2593/hls.m3u8');
            hls.attachMedia(streamAudio);           

        }

        plyr.setup(streamAudio);

        listener = new THREE.AudioListener();
        listener.hasPlaybackControl = true;
        perspectiveCamera.add(listener);
        audio = new THREE.Audio(listener);

        analyser = new THREE.AudioAnalyser(audio, fftSize);
        let frequencyData = analyser.getAverageFrequency();

        console.log(frequencyData);

        //let streamAnalyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();

        //source = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(streamAudio);
        //source.connect(audioContext.destination);
```

```
    <audio preload="none" id="player" hidden="hidden" controls crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <script src="https://cdn.plyr.io/1.8.2/plyr.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/hls.js/latest/hls.js"></script>
```

The commented code represents other methods I tried with no success. The audio stream works but I am unable to read any frequency data which is what I am hoping to achieve. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to connect a particular `AudioNode` with another one it only works if they both belong to the same `AudioContext`. To achieve that you could either use [`AudioContext.setContext`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/audio/AudioContext.setContext) to change the `AudioContext` used by three.js or you could just re-use the internal `AudioContext` created by three.js.

```js
const source = new MediaElementAudioSourceNode(
    listener.context,
    { mediaElement: streamAudio }
);
```

Please note that you need to use a `MediaElementAudioSourceNode` instead of a `MediaStreamAudioSourceNode` when connecting a media element.

You can then connect it to the input of the `AudioListener` like this:

```js
source.connect(listener.getInput());
```

In case this doesn't work it might be worth double-checking that `listener.context.state` actually says the `AudioContext` is `'running'`.

And last but not least you might run into a CORS issue in case the server which serves the audio assets doesn't allow the page to inspect the response. You can check this by replacing your `source` with an `OscillatorNode`. If that works without any problems but the HLS stream doesn't you probably need to change the server's CORS configuration.

```js
const source = new OscillatorNode(listener.context);

source.connect(listener.getInput());
source.start();
```